# 403 Forbidden in Node.js while sending email using sendgrid

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, sendgrid

I am designing a contact page in which UI is rendered using React. I have a form which is supposed to send email on submit. Here is the UI code for handling submit:

```
    handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    this.setState({
        disabled: true
    });

    Axios.post('http://localhost:3040/api/email', this.state)
        .then( res => {
            if(res.data.success){

              this.setState({
                disabled: false,
                emailSent: true
              });
            } else{
                this.setState({
                    disabled: false,
                    emailSent: false
                });
            }
        })
        .catch(err => {
            this.setState({
                disabled: false,
                emailSent: false
            });
        });
}
```

The api to send email is written in Node.js. Used @sendgrid//mail to trigger send. On debugging I can see that the form values are reaching the api but on send it throws 403 Forbidden error. Here is the api code:

```
app.post('/api/email', (req, res, next) => {
sendGrid.setApiKey('<Generated key in sendgrid>');
const msg = {
    to: 'some@email.com',
    from: req.body.email,
    subject: 'Website Contact Page',
    text: req.body.message
}

sendGrid.send(msg).then(result => {
    res.status(200).json({
        success: true
    });
})
.catch(err => {
    console.log('error: ', err);
    res.status(401).json({
        success: false
    });
});
});
```

The following is the error trace I am getting in the VSCode console while debugging:

```
stack:"Error: Forbidden
at axios.then.catch.error (c:\react\portfolio-api\node_modules\@sendgrid\client\src\classes\client.js:105:29)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)"
```

**proto**:Error {constructor: , toString: , toJSON: }

Not sure why its giving me Forbidden error. Please let me know if I need to add more info here. Thanks in advance :)

EDIT:- 
Followed the doc here at sendgrid to create an API key and used the same in sendGrid.setApiKey().

[image]

Comment: It seems likely you have an invalid Sendgrid API key.

Comment: Crosscheked the api key and they are alright. Edited the question adding image from the place where I am getting api key.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To be able to send email from sendgrid, you need to setup Single Sender Verification or Domain Verification.

Please check the [docs](https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/sending-email/sender-identity/) to verify sender.

> To ensure our customers maintain the best possible sender reputations
> and to uphold legitimate sending behavior, we require customers to
> verify their Sender Identities. A Sender Identity represents your
> “From” email address—the address your recipients will see as the
> sender of your emails.
>
> You can verify one or more Sender Identities using either Domain
> Authentication or Single Sender Verification.

In your api application console log, the error message must be like this:
(to see the real error message in the reactjs side, you need to use `err.response.data`.

> The from address does not match a verified Sender Identity. Mail
> cannot be sent until this error is resolved.

Comment: For me I needed to update the From field in the message body to the verified ail account associated with the sendGrid account.